# Map a given amount of points in space to form a number

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, math, computer-science

I wonder if there's an easy way to map a given amount of points in space to form a number?

For example: if I have 14 points, and I want to form the number 4
I'd get something like this

[image: number 4 created using 14 dots in space]

though if I had only 6 dots and still wanted to create the same number I'd get something like this:

[image: number 4 created using 6 dots in space]

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck getting a good answer from an art & design community. If I had to do this, I'd start by defining the minimum number of points for each digit along with the configuration of those points. Then, I'd allocate extra points to break up larger gaps into smaller ones roughly equally around the digit.

E.g., your 6-dot 4 might be the base case (so reject an input smaller than 6), then each segment (between pairs of adjacent points in the base case) gets 1/5 of the extra points spread evenly between the pair, with some ordering of the segments to cover cases when the additional points don't divide equally by 5.